# WordPress custom post type pagination returns 404 page error

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, http-status-code-404, custom-post-type

I created a custom post type that is the same name as a page of mine. I fixed that with custom code and that is working now:

```php
'has_archive' => false,
'rewrite' => array(
'slug' =>'case-studies',
'with_front' => false
```

But now when clicking a pagination link in my custom post type "case-studies" listing of posts (or enter a URL like `www.beezer.com/case-studies/page/2`), I get the 404 a page.

I have tried lots of custom code, including using Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer but it doesn't work.

```php
function my_pagination_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('case-studies/([^/]+)?(:/([0-9]+))?/?$', 'index.php?category_name=case-studies&paged=$matches[1]', 'top'); 
} 

add_action('init', 'my_pagination_rewrite');
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - please change 'has_archive' into 'true'

```
'has_archive' => true
```

And could you please share more detail code? I mean code which creates CPT and archive page.